# Tell eclipse to reload environment variables

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm setting an environment variable in a .bat file using `set` and `setx` which is executed by my java application.

But the next time I run my application the environment variables are back to their old values - I have to restart Eclipse for the changes to take effect.

How can I tell eclipse to reload environment variables each time I run my application?

Comment: Am I getting this correct? Your program executes a batch file that is included in your Eclipse project, and when you update the batch file with new values for your environment variables, it does not seem to work as expected when you run your program?

Comment: The batch file itself updates the environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables set with "set" are set for the current process and its children. If you leave the process, the values are lost.

The "setx" command sets an environment variable in the system environment. But the values are read into the process only on restart. So eclipse still has the old environment variables and started processes will inherit these.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to change the environment setting of the parent process.

Answer (score 10):

You can exit and start your eclipse instead of restarting it.  It should just work fine then.

Comment: I thought it was.  But apparently eclipse didn't reload environment variables for me when I restarted my eclipse.  You can try running the command with built-in terminal of eclipse and see if it works.  I exit my eclipse and then start it again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tell eclipse to reload environment variables each time I run my application?

Yes, You can easily define/simulate your Environment variables configurations during running the application inside Eclipse **without need to restart it + without need to update them externally from your system**:
Using `Run Configurations...`

[image]
[image]